# update en cadena

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo una tabla que tiene varias tareas, la idea es "terminar una" e iniciar otra, pero no se como formular una consulta asi

tengo lo siguiente:

```
create table tareas( 
id int not null PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
idvinedo int not null, idplantacion int not null, 
nombre varchar(50) not null, 
duracion varchar(50) not null, 
orden int not null, 
FOREIGN KEY (idvinedo) REFERENCES vinedo(id), 
FOREIGN KEY (idplantacion) REFERENCES plantaciones(id));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es que activo pase a 0 y a 1 en la siguiente fila, orden guarda correlativamente las tareas, por lo que puede servir para guiarse de cual es la siguiente fila a cambiar

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que pondrías la fila que tuviese activo 1 a 0 y la siguiente, según el valor de orden, pasaría a ser activo 1?

Comment: exactamente @JaviMollá, pero tambien se debiera determinar si existe alguna otra fila para seguir

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas dos updates. Suponiendo que el orden es único y correlativo, puedes actualizar el campo activo según el valor del orden de la tarea que esté activa en ese momento y que se haya terminado:

Para obtener el orden de la tarea activa (También podrías añadir como parámetro el id si lo sabes para asegurar mejor la consulta):

```
select orden from tareas where activo = 1;
```

Para marcar como terminada la actual y pasar a la siguiente:

```
update tareas set activo = 0 where orden = $orden;
update tareas set activo = 1 where orden = $orden + 1;
```

Todas estas consultas podrían ir en una transacción para evitar que se modifiquen los datos desde otro proceso

EDITO: Si necesitas saber si hay otra tarea después de la actual, puedes buscar por el orden si hay algún registro que sea posterior. Esto lo harías antes de hacer el segundo update:

```
select orden from tareas where orden > $orden;
```

Comment: el problema que tengo con esa respuesta, es que buscaba evitar ese select, tambien lo habia pensado asi, pero no soluciona mi problema

Comment: Dependiendo de la base de datos que uses, puedes consultar las filas afectadas por un update así, al realizar el segundo, sabrás si había algún proceso posterior que se vaya a ejecutar, evitando tener que hacer un select de nuevo